# Update exsisting image on HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on a small project for my companies end of year game jam. I am using HTML canvas for the first time and have reached a point where I am stuck.

I have images of the team members on a canvas. What I am trying to do is, when I click on their image, that will be the imaage that is used.

To start with I have a default image as the selected image:

```
let selectedImage = 'default.png';
```

I am then setting the inital image to the selected image:

```
const bird = {
     curImg: selectedImage,
     ...
```

When the user clicks on the image on the canvas, I am trying to update the image that will be used in the game:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    let coords = getCursorPosition(canvas, e);
    if (coords['x'] > 10 && coords['x'] < 75) {
        selectedImage = "Akshay.png";
    }
},
```

This should then replace the current default.png image with the selected Akshay.png image but the image on the canvas is not changing. I can see the selectedImage variable is updating to Akshay.png, but the default image remains. I have tried adding the draw method after updating selectedImage but it still wont change:

```
bird.draw();
```

I am not sure I am going wrong on this one, but I would appreciate any advice, and I could provide further code or info if required.

Thank you for any help with this.

EDIT: Added Canvas code.

Here is the draw method from the player:

```
const bird = {
     curImg: selectedImage,
     animations :
        [
            {sprite : new Image()},
            {sprite : new Image()},
            {sprite : new Image()},
            {sprite : new Image()},
        ],
    rotatation : 0,
    x : 50,
    y :100,
    speed : 0,
    gravity : .120,
    thrust : 3.0,
    frame:0,
    draw : function() {
        let h = this.animations[this.frame].sprite.height;
        let w = this.animations[this.frame].sprite.width;
        sctx.save();
        sctx.translate(this.x,this.y);
        sctx.rotate(this.rotatation*RAD);
        sctx.drawImage(this.animations[this.frame].sprite,-w/2,-h/2);
        sctx.restore();
    },
    update : function() {
```

There is this as well for the animations which I am still working on:

```
bird.animations[0].sprite.src="img/bird/devs/" + selectedImage;
bird.animations[1].sprite.src="img/bird/devs/" + selectedImage;
bird.animations[2].sprite.src="img/bird/devs/" + selectedImage;
bird.animations[3].sprite.src="img/bird/devs/" + selectedImage;
```

And here is the update function:

```
function update()
 {
  bird.update();  
  gnd.update();
  pipe.update();
  UI.update();
 }
 function draw()
 {
    // sctx.fillStyle = "#30c0df";
    sctx.fillRect(0,0,scrn.width,scrn.height)
    bg.draw();
    pipe.draw();
    
    bird.draw();
    gnd.draw();
    UI.draw();
 }
```

I have tried Google searches and asked a friend but still cannot figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: It would definitely be useful to see the canvas code that's doing the drawing.

Comment: I have updated the code. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this the right way to do it, but I got it working but updating the animations src:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    let coords = getCursorPosition(canvas, e);
    if (coords['x'] > 10 && coords['x'] < 75) {
        bird.animations[0].sprite.src = "img/bird/devs/Akshay.png";
        bird.animations[1].sprite.src = "img/bird/devs/Akshay.png";
        bird.animations[2].sprite.src = "img/bird/devs/Akshay.png";
        bird.animations[3].sprite.src = "img/bird/devs/Akshay.png";
    }
},
```